# I have an error while importing tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm using Python 3.6.0 and I downloaded tensorflow using `pip install tensorflow`, I tried several times to uninstall tensorflow and install another version of tensorflow but it didn't work... Which version of tensorflow is compatible for me? (I'm using now version 1.15.0)

This is the import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\adsp\train.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Have you tried tensorflow==1.15?

Comment: oh yes i'm sorry i'm currently using the 1.15 version not the 2.4.0

Comment: Do you have anaconda installed? If yes then try installing using conda: `conda install tensorflow` but first uninstall the already installed version using pip.

Comment: no i don't have anaconda

Comment: Try installing using this page instead of only pip: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows

Comment: Lookup the version of visual c++ redistributable required for the version of tensorflow you want and then install/update that redistributable on your system. I have had problems with redistributable and tensorflow in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the C++ redist libraries C++

[c++ redist lib](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Comment: Done. I installed the redistribution  ( Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019) and i restarted my pc. It still didn't work, is there any additional step after installing the redistribution? like move it to the tensorflow path or something

Comment: any reason why you are using tf 1.15? tf 2.0 requires  redist lib 2019

Comment: There's no reason, I just uninstalled the version 2.4 because I thought I need to install the compatible version of tensor flow with python 3.6.0 but it didn't work

Comment: Because someone told me to try the version 1.15 in case the version 2.4 didnt work

Comment: ic. i'm 100% sure it is because of the redist. I don't remember which redist is required for tf 1.5. If you wanna give it a try, install   1) python 3.7, tf 2.4 and redist for vs 2019. That combination always works for me. It is like a recipe.

Comment: okay, does it affect if i have many redistribution files?

Comment: no, you can have many diff version. Many diff package software are built using different versions of visual studio and they require them. They are c++ libraries.

Comment: okay thank you so much. I'll try the combination

Comment: I tried the combination and still i get the same error :(

Comment: what is your OS version?

Comment: try to uninstall the vc++ redist lib 2015-2019 and install it again. tf is written in c++, python is just a wrapper on top of the c++ libraries and in order to load it, those redist libs are needed.

Comment: you can try something which is not really required if the redist lib is installed properly. You can add the folder where you have the redist *.DLL files to your Path.

Comment: i'm using windows 10

Comment: Same as my 3 machines and all my co-workers. Did you change the path? I know how frustrating it is but while tt can't find those dll, it won't work

Comment: you could use anaconda, it is super easy. 1) Install anaconda individual edition, 2) Open Anaconda Navigator 3) Create a new environment called tf. (choose python 3.7)  4) Still on the UI, install tensorfolow on your tf environment. It takes a minute and always works.

Answer (score 0):

you could use anaconda, it is super easy. 1) Install anaconda individual edition, 2) Open Anaconda Navigator 3) Create a new environment called tf. (choose python 3.7) 4) Still on the UI, install tensorfolow on your tf environment. It takes a minute and always works.